# PySpark partitioned parquet taking long to load, even with specified schema

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

**Setting:** I have a folder with ~1300 partitioned parquet files (say, `C:\Project Data\Data-*.parquet)` where * is a counter and each file is around 8MB in size. All files have the same schema.

I am running PySpark in local mode as below. When I try to read the partitioned parquet files using

```
#initiate spark session
conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set('spark.driver.memory', '3g')
spark = (
    SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[10]")
    .config(conf=conf)
    .appName("Spark Local")
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

```
#get schema from one file (this cell works fine)
df_sample = spark.read.parquet(r"C:\Project Data\Data-0.parquet")
schema = df_sample.schema
```

```
#read all files
df = spark.read.format("parquet")\
     .schema(schema)\
     .load(r"C:\Project Data\Data-*.parquet")
```

**Issue**: it takes awfully long for pyspark to execute that cell. It looks like it attempts to load all of the data in memory (as my memory consumption slowly increases), whereas I was under the impression that it does so lazily (and so loading and showing first couple of lines should be very fast). But clearly something else is going on. I am a new spark user and would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some potential considerations:

1. When operating locally, the effective parallelism is constrained by the number of physical cores on the machine. If, for example, there are 2 CPUs, your parallelism is capped at 2.
2. You're encountering a common challenge in distributed systems known as the **small file problem.** Given your 8MB file size, significantly smaller than the block size of 128MB, each file triggers a task on its respective node. This process of opening, reading, and closing repeats 1300 times for your 1300 files, generating overhead on the master and creating multiple executors.

To address this, consider concatenating these files into larger, 128MB-sized files. This consolidation should yield noticeable improvements in performance.